Why username from profile disappear of the refresh page. Node.js
I did login and registration with node.js. Everything is working, and when I login, I can see a name of the user, but when I refresh the page, the name disappears. What I did wrong, please can you give me some advice?
index.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('./models/User')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false)

const bcryptSalt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const jwtSecret = 'jkjff8f7sdfsd8sjds9';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors({
    credentials:true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
}));

console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)

mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGODB_LINK)
.then( () => console.log( 'We were connect to Mongodb'))
.catch( (err) => console.log(err)) 

app.get('/api/test', (req,res) => {
    res.json('test ok')
})

app.post('/api/register', async (req,res) => {
    const {name,email,password } = req.body;
  
    try {
        const userDoc =  await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcryptSalt),
        })
        res.json({userDoc});
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(422).json(e)
    }
  
});

app.post('/api/login', async (req,res) => {
    const {email,password} = req.body;
    const userDoc = await User.findOne({email});
    if (userDoc) {
      const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
      if (passOk) {
        jwt.sign({
          email:userDoc.email,
          id:userDoc._id
        }, jwtSecret, {}, (err,token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.cookie('token', token).json(userDoc);
        });
      } else {
        res.status(422).json('pass not ok');
      }
    } else {
      res.json('not found');
    }
  });
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const {name,email,_id} = await User.findById(userData.id);
      res.json({name,email,_id});
    });
  } else {
    res.json(null)
  }
  
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('post is listening on 4000')
})

UserContext.jsx
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";


export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UserContextProvider({children}) {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
    useEffect( () => {
        if(!user) {
            axios.get('/profile').then(({data}) => {
                setUser(data);
                setReady(true)
            })
        }
    }, [])
    return(

        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser,ready}}>
        {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

RegisterPage.jsx
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
export default function RegisterPage() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    async function registerUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/register', {
            name,
            email,
            password,
          },
          {
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include',
          });
          alert('Registration successful. Now you can log in');
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Registration failed. Please try again later');
        }
      }
    return (
       
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
           <div className="mb-64">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4" >Register</h1>
            <form className="max-x-md mx-auto " onSubmit={registerUser}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Joy Doe"
                    value={name}
                    onChange={ev => setName(ev.target.value)}/>
                <input type="email" placeholder="your@email.com"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={ev=> setEmail(ev.target.value)}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}/>
                <button className="primary">Register</button>
              <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
              Already a member?
              <Link className="underline text-black" to={'/login'}> Login</Link>
              </div>
            </form>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

LoginPage.jsx
import { useContext, useState } from "react"
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from "axios";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";
export default function LoginPage() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
    // http://localhost:4000/login
    const {setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
    async function handleLoginSubmit(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        try {
            const {data} = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/login', 
                {
                    email, 
                    password
                },
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    credentials: 'include',
                  }
            );
            setUser(data)
            alert('Login successful');
            setRedirect(true);
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Login failed')
        }
    }
    if (redirect) {
        return <Navigate to={'/'}/> 
    }
    return (
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
           <div className="mb-64">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4" >Login</h1>
            <form className="max-x-md mx-auto " onSubmit={handleLoginSubmit}>
                <input type="email" placeholder="your@email.com"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={ev => setEmail(ev.target.value)}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password"
                    value={password}
                onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}/>
                <button className="primary">Login</button>
              <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
              Don't have an account yet?
              <Link className="underline text-black" to={'/register'}> Register now</Link>
              </div>
            </form>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

Get request localhost:4000 does not work, shows 404 undefined. And when i login I can see user Name, but  profile response is null, should be name and email. If i refresh the page i have to login again
I searched answer but could not find anything
